# Facebook API - Comment share links to wrong URL

Tags: javascript, facebook

Alright so I'm setting up comment boxes across my site. Here's an example of one:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://whisperingforest.org/#/quote/60" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

For some reason instead of linking to the commented URL, it links people to `https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=435066949857522`

**I can't figure out why it's doing so, any suggestions?**

Just in case here's my FB initiation (after the opening body tag):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '467744490017837',
          status     : false,
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Comment: Same problem. Wrong url on :og_title with wrong app_id (same as yours https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=435066949857522).

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a proxy url (plain html, not a javascript application as your page) with open graph tags for Facebook scraper (og:title, og:description, og:image, og:sitename, og:type)  and a javascript redirect for real users. Example:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
     <meta property="og:title" content="Quote #60" />
     <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
     <meta property="og:url" content="http://whisperingforest.org/quote.php?id=80" />
     <meta property="og:image" content="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=thumb" />
     <meta property="og:description" content="some description or maybe whole quote?" />
     <meta property="og:site_name" content="Whispering Forest" />
     <script>document.location.href="http://whisperingforest.org/#/quote/60"</script>
 </head>
 </html>
```

Of course it should be generated server-side and you must change og:url to your real script url.

Answer (score 0):

To add facebook comment system, you can also use this method in following way:

1.In your  tag, add this meta tag-

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your app ID"/>
```

2.Now, wherever you want your comment box to appear, simply add following line of code so you will not need to write that javascript in your  tag-

```
   <div id="fbcomments">
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
       <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
       <fb:comments href="URL of your webpage" width="880"></fb:comments>
       </div>
```

3.Also, you can change language in which your comments appear by replacing en_US with respective language.

A useful link : http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-ultimate-guide-to-implementing-facebook-comments-on-your-blog--wp-23855

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="fbcomments">
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
       <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
       <fb:comments href="URL of your webpage" width="680"></fb:comments>
       </div>
```

Use above code to show comment box. Also do add following meta tag in your tag-

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your app ID"/>
```